# Kotlin: NoClassDefFoundError - Android Studio shows classes that shouldn't be there

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kapt

I just updated my small Android project to Kotlin. And as a result I replaced `annotationProcessor` with `kapt` everywhere it was used in my `build.gradle` file. My problem is that although I don't use Guava Android Studio is allowing me to e.g. import `com.google.common.base.Preconditions` and use it, but when it comes to launching the app `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown.

So I assume that Guava isn't compiled with my project () and that's why I am getting this error. But then why Android Studio allowing me to use it?

Comment: Please show how exactly you're configuring annotation processors in your build.gradle.

Comment: @yole I was mixing `annotationProcessor`s for my AutoValue Java code and `kapt` for e.g. PaperParcel library. Once I migrated my models to Kotlin and removed AutoValue (so now only `kapt` is used) the problem disappeared.